# Java help: using loops to print the squares of values in between start arg and end arg

Tags: java, loops

So I'm new to java, please excuse any messy code etc.

I have to make a program that prints out the squared value of a start and end argument declared in the command line, as well as the squares of the values in between.

This is the code I have so far, it's very rough, but I need help getting the variables in between to print out.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int start;
      int end;
      int start2;
      int end2;

      start  = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
      end    = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
      start2 = start*start;
      end2   = end*end;

      if (args.length == 2) {
           for (int i = start; i <= end; i++){
                   System.out.println("The square of "+start+" is "  +start2);
                   System.out.println("The square of "+end+  " is "  +end2);
                   return;
                }
  }
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Calculate the square of `i`

Comment: As a sidenode, you should check `if (args.length == 2)`(it would be better to check `args.length > 1`) before assigning `arg[0]` and `arg[1]`.

Comment: update your for loop SOP `System.out.println("The square of "+i+" is "  +i*i);`

Answer (score 4):

You can calculate the square of start to end **inside** the loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int start  = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int end    = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

    if (args.length == 2)
        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
            System.out.println("The square of " + i + " is "  + i*i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            int start;
            int end;

            start  = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            end    = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

            if (args.length == 2)
            {
                for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
                    System.out.println("The square of "+i+" is "  +i*i);
                return;
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can calculate it inside the loop

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    if (args.length == 2){
       int start  = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
       int end    = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
       for (int i = start; i <= end; i++){
          System.out.println("The square of " + i + " is "  + i*i);
       }
    }
}
```

**Note :** Check the length first, and short-circuit your condition if the length isn't equal 2 before doing any operation to avoid `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`